# Random number between two numbers without overflowing

Tags: c#, random

I realize this question has been asked countless times, but it seems that every answer does not take into account overflows.

The suggested method is as follows

```
public static double BoundedNext( double min, double max )
{
  var random = new Random( Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode() );
  return ( random.NextDouble() * ( max - min ) ) + min;
}
```

In just about every single case, this works as it should. However, it does not properly handle cases where an overflow occurs, such as `BoundedNext(Double.MinValue, Double.MaxValue)`. The issue becomes even trickier in languages like C#, where an overflowed `double` equates to `-/+ infinity`.

The simple solution would be to just use a larger type, but **I would like a solution that is able to produce a random number between two numbers, for each explicit type, that can handle overflow cases.**

Comment: Tip: `Random()` will work just as well as trying to generate your own random seed, and it's much less effort. And you may like to look at this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice solution for this, as your question is well in place, I will share it with you, as I always keep it in my backlog files just in case:

```
  static Random random = new Random();

    // Note, max is exclusive here!
    public static List<int> GenerateRandom(int count, double min, double max)
    {

        if (max <= min || count < 0 || 
                // max - min > 0 required to avoid overflow
                (count > max - min && max - min > 0))
        {
            // need to use 64-bit to support big ranges (negative min, positive max)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Range " + min + " to " + max + 
                    " (" + ((Double)max - (Double)min) + " values), or count " + count + " is illegal");
        }

        // generate count random values.
        HashSet<int> candidates = new HashSet<int>();

        // start count values before max, and end at max
        for (double top = max - count; top < max; top++)
        {
            // May strike a duplicate.
            // Need to add +1 to make inclusive generator
            // +1 is safe even for MaxVal max value because top < max
            if (!candidates.Add(random.Next(min, top + 1))) {
                // collision, add inclusive max.
                // which could not possibly have been added before.
                candidates.Add(top);
            }
        }

        // load them in to a list, to sort
        List<int> result = candidates.ToList();

        // shuffle the results because HashSet has messed
        // with the order, and the algorithm does not produce
        // random-ordered results (e.g. max-1 will never be the first value)
        for (int i = result.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {  
            int k = random.Next(i + 1);  
            int tmp = result[k];  
            result[k] = result[i];  
            result[i] = tmp;  
        }  
        return result;
    }

    public static List<int> GenerateRandom(int count)
    {
        return GenerateRandom(count, 0, Double.MaxValue);
    }
```

This solution was written in `Int64` so I tried to adopt it for `double` as much as I could for you. 
Take it and revise it for your needs.

- **Please note the comment suggesting what is required to avoid overflow**